# Mathematical letter in glossaries name={\ensuremath{\mathbf{A_{L}}}-Wert:},

Tags: xetex, glossaries, glossary

There is a problem with the space after the the `\newglossaryentry{al-wert}`. This mathematical `$A_{L}$` produces the error. The second issue is that the rows of the 2 columns are not properly aligned. Please take a look at the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=210mm:297mm,open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage[outer=20mm,inner=24.6mm,vmargin=14.5mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

%% Koma options
\KOMAoption{toc}{listof}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half-}

%% Packages
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

%% Page style scrheadings
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,pagestyleset=standard,markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}

%% Sinunitx
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{misc/siunitxext}
\sisetup{text-series-to-math=true,text-family-to-math=true}
\DeclareSIUnit\noop{\relax}

%% Glossary
\usepackage[automake,style=mcoltree,stylemods=mcols,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries-extra}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
\makeglossaries

% Glossary

%% A
\newglossaryentry{a-betrieb}{
    name={A-Betrieb:},
    description={\textit{(Arbeitspunktangabe von Leistungsverstärk\-ern)}: Beim A-Betrieb liegt der Arbeitspunkt auf der Mitte der Eingangskennlinie des Verstärkers. Dadurch arbeitet der A-Verstärker mit den geringsten Verzerrungen, weil die Aussteuerung, auf den teillinearen Bereich der Kennlinie beschränkt bleibt. Der Wirkungsgrad beträgt nur \qty{40}{\percent}, da ständig ein hoher Ruhestrom fließt.}
}

\newglossaryentry{ab-betrieb}{
    name={AB-Betrieb:},
    description={\textit{(Arbeitspunktangabe von Leistungsverstärkern)}: Beim AB-Betrieb liegt der Arbeitspunkt im unteren Teil der Eingangskennlinie des Verstärkers. Der Wirkungsgrad beträgt \qtylist{50;60}{\percent}. Man unterscheidet bei Röhrenverstärkern zwischen $\text{AB}_{1}$ und $\text{AB}_{2}$ Betrieb. Der Index 1 gibt an, dass das Steuergitter niemals positiv gegenüber der Kathode wird, so dass kein Gitterstrom fließt und der Verstärker leistungslos gesteuert wird. Im Gegensatz hierzu kennzeichnet der Index 2, dass der Verstärker bis in den Gitterstrombereich gesteuert wird. Dadurch erhält man eine höhere Ausgangsleitung. Allerdings erhöht sich der Grad der Verzerrung, der durch eine Zunahme der Intermodulationsprodukte gekennzeichnet ist. Zudem muß während der Gitterstromphasen Steuerleistung aufgebracht werden.}
}

\newglossaryentry{ablenkverstärker}{
    name={Ablenkverstärker:},
    description={\textit{(Verstärker für Bild- und Zeilenablenkung zum Aufbau eines Bildrasters)}: Um auf dem Bildschirm einer Kathodenstrahlröhre (Fernsehbildröhre) ein Zeilenraster aufbauen zu können, muß der Elektronenstrahl Zeile für Zeile über die gesammte Bildröhre möglichst verzerrungsfrei (linear) geschrieben werden. Die hierfür benötigten Zeilen- und Bildablenksignale besitzen Sägezahnform. Sie werden im Zeilen- und Bildablenkungsverstärker auf die erforderliche Amplitude verstärkt, um den Bildschirm voll ausschreiben zu können.}
}

\newglossaryentry{abschlusswiderstand}{
    name={Abschlusswiderstand:},
    description={\textit{(Der Leistung nach angepasster Widerstand am Ende einer Leitung)}: Eine Leitung ist dann abgeschlossen, wenn sich an ihrem Ende ein Widerstand befindet, dessen Wert gleich dem Wellenwiderstand $Z_{L}$ der Leitung ist. Dieser Abschlusswiderstand nimmt alle zugeführte Energie auf, so dass keine Reflexionen auftreten und das Stehwellenverhältnis gleich 1 ist. Abschlusswiderstände werden im Amateurfunk meist als künstliche Antennen eingesetzt (dummy load), um genaue Leistungsmessungen zu ermöglichen.}
}


\newglossaryentry{al-wert}{
    name={\ensuremath{\mathbf{A_{L}}}-Wert:},
    description={\textit{(Faktor zum Berechnen von Induktivitäten)}: Der $A_{L}$-Wert oder Induktionsfaktor gibt die Induktivität je Windung für einen bestimmten Spulenkörper an. Die Gesamtinduktivität $L$ wird durch die quadratische Zunahme der Induktivität mit der Windungzahl $W$ berechnet: $L = A_{L} \cdot W^2$. Der höhere $A_{L}$-Wert eines zu wählenden Kernmaterials gibt hiernach an, dass man bei kleine Windungszahl benötigt, um die gleiche Induktivität zu erhalten, für die man mehr Windungen bei geringerem $A_{L}$-Wert aufwenden müßte.}
}
 

%% Define default language
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

%% Main serif font for German (Latin alphabet) text
\setmainfont{IBM Plex Sans Condensed}
\setsansfont{IBM Plex Sans Condensed}
\setmonofont{IBM Plex Mono}

\begin{document}

%% Glossaries
\printglossaries
\glsaddall
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: correct your code, the brackets are wrong in various places, eg.. `\usepackage\[no-math\]{fontspec}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've fixed that. Looked like a mistake when writing the question and not the code.

Comment: It doesn't see $A_L$ as starting with an `A` and sorts it in front of `A`. (If you change `A-Betrieb` to `B-Betrieb` you see the same spacing between `Abschlusswiderstand` and `B-Betrieb`. Maybe there's a `sort` key.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about). It helps keep the site clean, I see you haven't accepted any previous answers too.

Answer (score 2):

The math-mode `A_L` doesn't get recognized as starting with an `A` and gets sorted in its own category. Use the `sort` key to correct this:

```
\newglossaryentry{al-wert}{
    name={$A_L$-Wert:},
    sort={AL-Wert:}, 
%   sort={A-L-Wert:}, % (after A-Betrieb)
    description={…}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.